# Ant: error: cannot find symbol: symbol: class Server: location: class SslContextFactory. Even though the JAR is in the classpath

Tags: java, compiler-errors, ant, jetty, classpath

I'm building this project (with modifications): https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect

I have the following code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
public class HttpsReceiver extends SourceConnector implements BinaryContentTypeResolver {
    @Override
    public void onStart() throws ConnectorTaskException {
...
            SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
```

When I build with the included Ant script, I get an error:

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\spinsci\connect-3.8.1\server>ant compile -debug
...
compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\spinsci\connect-3.8.1\server\classes
...
    [javac] Compiling 822 source files to C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\spinsci\connect-3.8.1\server\classes
    [javac] Using modern compiler
    [javac] Compilation arguments:
    [javac] '-d'
    [javac] 'C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\spinsci\connect-3.8.1\server\classes'
    [javac] '-classpath'
...
...;C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\spinsci\connect-3.8.1\server\lib\jetty\jetty-util-9.4.24.v20191120.jar;...
...
    [javac] C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\spinsci\connect-3.8.1\server\src\com\mirth\connect\connectors\https\HttpsReceiver.java:311: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
    [javac]                                                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Server
    [javac]   location: class SslContextFactory
```

However, that class and JAR does exist!

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\spinsci\connect-3.8.1\server>jar -tf C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\spinsci\connect-3.8.1\server\lib\jetty\jetty-util-9.4.24.v20191120.jar | grep Server
org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory$Server.class
```

So why is Ant complaining that it can't find the class when it is available?

Here is the `build.xml`:

```
<target name="init">
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>
...
<target name="compile" depends="clean, init, create-javadocs">
    <!-- compile the source -->
    <mkdir dir="${classes}" />

    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" debug="on" includeAntRuntime="false">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
```

I tried adding the line

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.Server;
```

But then Eclipse complained with an error `The import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.Server collides with another import statement`.

Comment: That's probably a version mismatch. The `SslContextFactory.Server` class does not exist in version 9.4.9, but exists in 9.4.20. Check for older versions on the classpath. `+++` Adding the `.....SslContextFactory.Server` import makes no sense - it'd allow you to refer to the class by lone `Server`, that's not what you need.

Comment: I'm using `jetty-util-9.4.24.v20191120.jar`. Hmm... I used `dir /s /b jetty*` and found `\server\lib\jetty-9.4.9` and `\server\lib\jetty` (which contains 9.4.24). Wow that was it. I deleted `jetty-9.4.9` and it got past that point!